# How to make a JS function apply to new HTML

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to build an invoicing system, and I'm a bit stuck. here's where I'm at:

```js
const invoiceUI = (function() {


  const getData = (async function() {
    const dropdown = document.querySelector(".DD");
    const data = await (await fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.egansites.com/sampleajax/index.php")).json();
    data.forEach(cur => {
      option = document.createElement('option');
      option.text = cur.item;
      dropdown.add(option);
    });
  })();

  const selectItem = async function() {
    let x = document.querySelector(".DD");
    let y = document.querySelector(".desc");
    const data = await (await fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.egansites.com/sampleajax/index.php")).json();
    data.forEach(cur => {
      if (x.value === cur.item) {
        y.value = `${cur.idesc}`;
      }
    })
  }

  async function addRow() {
    const data = await (await fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.egansites.com/sampleajax/index.php")).json();
    const table = document.querySelector(".tableBody")
    const select = document.createElement("select")
    select.classList.add("DD");
    select.innerHTML = "<option selected>Choose...</option>" + data.map(current => `<option >${current.item}</option>`).join("")
    const newRow =
      `<tr>

        <td>
        <div>
        ${select.outerHTML}
        </div>
        </td>

        <td>
        <input type="text" name="l112[]" style="width:100%" class="desc" disabled>
        </td>

        <td>
        <input type="text" name="l108Price[]" class="price tis">
        </td>

        <td>
        <input type="text" name="l108Qty[]" class="qty tis">
        </td>

        <td>
        <input type= "text" name="l108Amt[]" class="amt tis" disabled>
        </td>

        <td>
        <div>
        <button type="button" name="button"  class="addRow" style="background-color:Transparent; border:none; color:green;">
        <i class="fas fa-plus-circle addRow">
        </i>
        </button>
        </div>
        </td>

        </tr>`;
    // Inserting the string as a HTMLElement at the end of the table element
    table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newRow);
  }

  return {
    setupEL: function() {
      //document.querySelector(".DD").addEventListener('change', selectItem);
      
      document.addEventListener("change", ele => {
        if (ele.target.classList.contains("DD")) {
          selectItem();
        }
      })
      document.addEventListener("click", ele => {
        if (ele.target.classList.contains("addRow")) {
          addRow();
        }
      })
      // document.addEventListener("click", element=> {
      //   if (element.target.classList.contains("DD")) {
      //     getData();
      //   }
      // })
    }
  }
})();

const invoiceControl = (function(ui) {
  return {
    init: function() {
      ui.setupEL()
    }
  }
})(invoiceUI);

invoiceControl.init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Font Awesome CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">



</head>

<body>

  <main role="main">


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 offset-2">

        <table class="table thead-dark table-hover border-bottom" id="invoiceTable">

          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="width: 10%">Item</th>
              <th style="width: 50%">Description</th>
              <th style="width: 10%">Price</th>
              <th style="width: 5%">Qty</th>
              <th style="width: 10%">Amount</th>
              <th style=>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody class="tableBody">
            <tr id="invoiceTableRow">

              <td>
                <div>
                  <select class='DD'>
                    <option value="<Option1">Choose...</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td><input type="text" style="width:100%" name="l112[]" class="desc" disabled></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="l108Price[]" class="price tis money"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="l108Qty[]" class="qty tis quan"></td>
              <td><input type='text' name='l108Amt[]' class="amt tis" disabled></td>
              <td>
                <div><button type="button" name="button" class="addRow" style="background-color:Transparent; border:none; color:green;"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle addRow"></i></button></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>


  </main>
  <!-- /role main -->



</body>

</html>
```

Obviously, this is just a stripped down part of it. Everything work as I load it all (I made a special ajax server just for this query). The issue comes in after I create a new line in the table using the '+' button. The new line doesn't get the drop-down options. I know why too. I'm loading the async function on start, not when I click the '+' button. My question is, "How do I make this functionality apply to all subsequent lines, just not the first one?" I tried fixing it by adding:

```
 document.addEventListener("click", element=> {
    if (element.target.classList.contains("DD")) {
     getData();
    }
```

to the function that returns all the page's event handlers (a neat trick I learned from this site while searching for a solution), but that doesn't work at all.

As most of you can probably tell by now, I'm still new to JS. just the format of the code looks like it came from a classroom. I'm not quite ready for the Jquery library just yet, so if we can keep answers to vanilla JS, I'd appreciate it. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You're assigning an `IIFE` into a variable `invoiceUI `. That's of no use. Either remove it or just write `const invoiceUI = function(){}` without invoking it with `()`

Comment: When I do that, the first line doesn't get the drop-down items, nor do subsequent ones. I ended up doing that in the first place to set up modules for the program to run in. Is that a bad thing to do?

Comment: Since the data you are feeding to the select is same why not get it first in a variable and iterate the data and add options on each row addition.And also while adding row add listener dynamically to new select.`const select=document.createElement("select")
    select.classList.add("DD");
    select.innerHTML="<option selected>Choose...</option>"+selectData.map(option =>  `<option >${option.item}</option>`).join("") ` and use select.outerHTML to add it in the string

Comment: As I read it, this makes sense. However, I'll need to figure out how to do it.

Comment: OK, so i bee at this for a while now and I figured out and applied the solution from @Supercool. now I can't get my selectItem() function to fire on new rows added by the addRow() function. I trid updating my event listener to a if/then to no avail. I have a feeling ts because the row is added asynchronously and the event listener is fired synchronously, but I don't understand how to fix it.